# is theres a way to make one variable to have multiple meanings

Tags: python, list

is there any way that i make x = "y" = "Y", so when i type x == "y" or x == "Y" both shows True.
ive tried :

```
x = ["y", "Y"]

x == "y"

x == "Y"
```

but both still says False

Comment: You could make `x` an instance of a class that overrides `__eq__` with a counter that toggles between what that should return but you'd be insane to do this

Comment: It can help to explain what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like you may just be trying to compare a string in a case-insensitive manner, so something like `x.lower() == "y"` may be all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need `.any()` and check each element with 'y' or 'Y' like below:

```
>>> [i == 'y' for i in x]
[True, False]

>>> any(i == 'y' for i in x)
True


>>> [i == 'Y' for i in x]
[False, True]

>>> any(i == 'Y' for i in x)
True
```

Comment: Yeah! I am sorry to be late!

Answer (score 1):

This would work. Please check if it did:

```
x = ("y", "Y")
for i in enumerate(x):
    print(i[1] == "y")
```

What this code does is it creates a tuple of both the values and then runs a for loop using an enumerate class, which tells the current index as well as the current index's value and stores it in a variable (the variable is 'i' in here). Example - i = (0, "y") it means that its the first loop (0) and the value is 'y'. then it checks whether i[1] ("y" as per the above example) is == "y" (or whatever) or not.

Hope this answer helped you solve your problem and understand it as well.